# Target a button listener that is inside a recycler view item that is inside a fragment

Tags: java, android, button, nullpointerexception

Here is the question: So I have a Fragment in which I have a recycler view ,with custom adapter, that stores a bunch of college cards that display a college ID and name. They also have a button on the right hand side. Here is the XML of a template of this card:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/gradientEnd"
    android:layout_margin="2dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/college_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="EXAMPLE COLLEGE"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/college_id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="ID: 1234567"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_college_details"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Details"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_bg"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

So because this is inside a recycler view that is inside of a fragment, when I try to create `setOnClickListener` for this button in `onCreateView()`, when I open the fragment the recycler view is in, it just crashes. I assume this is because the recycler view is populated inside a fragment at the same time I try to mess with the button and it simply can't see it as I get a`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference` exception. Here is the Fragments Java code:

```
public class CollegeFragment extends Fragment implements ItemClickListener{

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private CustomRecyclerAdapter customRecyclerAdapter;
    private List<CollegeItem> collegeItemList = new ArrayList<>();
    private DatabaseCollege dbCollege;
    private EditText cName, cId;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_college, container, false);

        dbCollege = new DatabaseCollege(getActivity());

        recyclerView = myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        customRecyclerAdapter = new CustomRecyclerAdapter(dbCollege.getCollegeData(), getActivity()); //populate recycler view with college cards

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(customRecyclerAdapter);
        customRecyclerAdapter.setItemClickListener(this);

        cId = myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.et_ipeds);
        cId.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                CollegeFragment.this.customRecyclerAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });

        Button details = myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_college_details);
        details.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //This line causes the crash 
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //do stuff
            }
        });


        return myFragmentView;

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v, int position) {
        String name = collegeItemList.get(position).getName();
        String id = collegeItemList.get(position).getId();
    }
}
```

So general question is: How do I write a code that is able to target a button setOnClickListener that resides within a generated item of a recycler view and recycler view itself is inside of a Fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do here is create an onClickListener on the button inside the holder which holds your layout on the top which defines your separate views inside the recycleview and then create whatever process you want to do inside that on click listener.
Here, i have added a sample code for your code.

```
holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
//process here.
}
```